# XML Payload using Node Soap package parse issue

Tags: node.js, soap, salesforce, wsdl, node-modules

I have a Salesforce XML Payload Which I need to Parse Using Node Soap package

```
const soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://devs3-nodelogger.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wsdlfiles/Workflow_outboundmessage_WSDL_CD.wsdl';
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);
    console.log(client.describe());
    console.log(client.describe().Notificationservice.Notification.notifications);
}
```

Using the client.describe() method I'm able to see what inputs to be passed to notifications method as below

```
input: {
    OrganizationId: 'ID|xsd:string|length,pattern',
    ActionId: 'ID|xsd:string|length,pattern',
    SessionId: 'xsd:string',
    EnterpriseUrl: 'xsd:string',
    PartnerUrl: 'xsd:string',
    'Notification[]': {
      Id: 'ID|xsd:string|length,pattern',
      sObject: [Object],
      targetNSAlias: 'tns',
      targetNamespace: 'http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound'
    }
  },
  output: { Ack: 'xsd:boolean' }
```

How to get proper response from Soap package.

I tried sending the inputs as JSON by converting the Inputs. But it didn't work